# function with for loop and variable creation

Tags: r, function, for-loop

I made the following function:

```
library(magicfor)
aufsum_func <- function(stes_zu_mo, proz_teil, taggeld) 
  {
  ko_mo_1 <- (4500+115)* stes_zu_mo*proz_teil
  er_mo_1 <- (19.8/500*30)*taggeld*stes_zu_mo*proz_teil
  magic_for(silent = T)
  for(p in 1:200)
    { 
    if(p==1)
      {
      aufsum_mo <- er_mo_1 - ko_mo_1  
      }
    else if(p>1 & p<=22)
      {
      aufsum_mo <- er_mo_1 *p + aufsum_mo - ko_mo_1     
      }
    else
      {
      aufsum_mo <- er_mo_1 *22 + aufsum_mo - ko_mo_1  
      }
    put(aufsum_mo)
    }
  temp <- magic_result_as_dataframe(iter = F)
  return(temp)
}

df_45_4 <- aufsum_func(stes_zu_mo=83230/12, proz_teil=0.4, taggeld=203)
df_45_5 <- aufsum_func(stes_zu_mo=83230/12, proz_teil=0.538, taggeld=203)
```

I always get  the following error:

```
 Error: object 'er_mo_1' not found
```

My question is why the object is not found? For me it looks like the function I wrote is jumping over the first two or even three Statements? otherwise the object should have been found by the function? So what I am doing wrong? Could you please help me to debug the function? I am quite new to writing functions so forgive me if the question is very easy to solve! :)

Comment: Not the error message I get: `Error in magic_for(silent = T) : could not find function "magic_for"` and some other undefined functions, but apparently no problem with `er_mo_1`

Comment: If I comment out `magic_for`, `put(aufsum_mo)` and `magic_result_as_dataframe` I don't get any error.

Comment: Sorry I used `library(magicfor)`. With your suggestions where does the temp come from?